# how to scroll to bottom of the page with jquery 1.10

Tags: jquery

I want to load more posts on scrolling to the bottom of the page.

I try this javascript code below, but instead of loading the post when the page is scrolling to the bottom, the post load when the page is scroll to the top.

```
//on scroll to append more posts 

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()  == $(document).height()) {
   var accessid =$('#currentid').val();
       var accessdiv =$('#currentdiv').val();

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
    url: "included/initiate2.php",
  data: {accessid:accessid,accessdiv:accessdiv}
  })
  .done(function(execution){
  $('#timeline').append(execution);
       testrun();
       run();
       previmg();
       pst_comment()

 }); 
 }
 });
```

I tried this code with jQuery 1.7 and then it works perfectly, but with jQuery 1.10 it works when the page is scrolled up.

Comment: What do you mean with "it works when the page is scrolled up"?

Comment: when i scrolled the page to the bottom and i scrolled it back to the top it will load post

Comment: i want to load more post on scroll to the botttom of the page